Rails 5 - Rspec Autoloading files with Dummy App
I have a strange issue, where I am upgrading a Rails 4 app to Rails 5.
The spec suite runs fine when the app is booted via Rails 4 mode.
However, when booting the app in Rails 5 mode, the spec suite has no reference to the test subject models. I now get unitialized constant for all models, when the specs try to run.
In my spec suite i have a dummy app, and i think its here that Im encountering the issue.
In my application.rb file within the Dummy app, i have the autoload configured as below:
config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib]
config.eager_load_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib]

In the test.rb, i have eager_loading turned off.
 config.eager_load = false

Im aware if changes with Zeitwork in Rails 5, but I cant figure out why the dummy app cant access the app/models and other files within the engine.
EDIT
I can get around teh issue to some degree, by adding requires to teh files that it cant load in my spec_helper.
# TODO: Review this, and the wider scope of autoloading.
require_relative '../../my_folder/app/models/foo'
require_relative '../../my_folder/app/models/bar'


Can you post an example of the error you are receiving? Almost all issues with Zietwerk autoloading have to do with improper namespacing and/or directory structure but we cannot determine if this is your issue without additional details. As an aside autoloading the lib directory is generally discouraged.
